# C++ data file not reading correctly when introducing ofstream?

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Ok so, this is gonna be a long one...

Explanation of what the project is supposed to do:

My final project is a bank teller system that stores all the account related data on a text files.
The file in question, **"accounts.txt"**, is where all the account data is stored. It is read and write, and behaves strangely when an ofstream is introduced...

The **"accounts.txt"** file is formated as follows

01481
554-00-8336
Jane Jones
1483 N. RealmSecond Ave., Burlington, VT 05401
564 425 5052
02650
727-22-1072
Jennifer Armstrong
1450 W. Main Rd., Burlington, VT 05401
202 545 5485

**it continues repeating the same ordered sets of information...**

One of the core parts of the program relies on reading these values into 5 separate arrays, each pertaining to type of data (name, address, etc).

I am going to dump the entire program because I think it might be necessary to fix the problem, just understand that the main function in question is **addAccount()** and is located at the bottom.

Note that the purpose of this function is to read the entire **accounts.txt** file line by line into memory, determine at what point the arrays used to store the file are being filled with empty data **(we were told by the course instructor to make the array size 100, meaning that most of the data read into the array is empty space)** get the desired account information from the user, update the file in memory, and rewrite the file...

also note that the file format was predetermined by the course instructor

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int TELLERS_SIZE = 5;
const int ACCOUNTS_SIZE = 100;
const string TELLERS_FILE = "tellers.txt";
const string ACCOUNTS_FILE = "accounts.txt";

int beginMenu();
bool login(string fileName);
int baseMenu();
void searchAccount(string fileName);
void addAccount(string fileName);

int main() {

    int beginSelection;

        do {

            beginSelection = beginMenu();

            if (beginSelection == 2) {
                return 0;
            }

            bool loginIsTrue = login(TELLERS_FILE);

            while (loginIsTrue) {

                int baseSelection = baseMenu();

                if (baseSelection == 1) {
                    addAccount(ACCOUNTS_FILE);
                }

                if (baseSelection == 4) {
                    searchAccount(ACCOUNTS_FILE);
                }

                if (baseSelection == 8) {
                    loginIsTrue = false;
                }

            }

        } while (beginSelection == 1);

}

// Print the fisrt menu and return selection
int beginMenu() {
    // Establish return value and validation
    int menuSelection;
    string userInput;
    bool menuSelectionIsValid = false;

    // Print options
    do {
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "[1] Login" << "\n";
        cout << "[2] Quit" << "\n";
        cout << "Please enter a selection";
        cout << "\n";
        getline(cin, userInput);

        // Validate input
        if (userInput == "1") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 1;
        }

        else if (userInput == "2") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 2;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input!" << "\n";
        }

    } while (!menuSelectionIsValid);

    return menuSelection;
}

// Perform login and return true or false
bool login(string fileName) {

    // Establish variables
    string username[TELLERS_SIZE];
    string password[TELLERS_SIZE];

    string usernameInput;
    string passwordInput;

    bool loginIsValid = false;

    // Establish fin
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "File cannot be opened " << fileName << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Read tellers.dat
    for (int i = 0; i < TELLERS_SIZE; i++) {
        fin >> username[i];
        fin >> password[i];
    }

        // Read user input
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Username: ";
        getline(cin, usernameInput);
        cout << "Password: ";
        getline(cin, passwordInput);

        // Verify login information
        for (int i = 0; i < TELLERS_SIZE; i++) {
            if (username[i] == usernameInput && password[i] == passwordInput) {
                cout << "Login succesful" << "\n";
                loginIsValid = true;
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Inform user of error
        cout << "Invalid username or password!" << "\n";
        return false;
}

// Print base functions menu and return selection
int baseMenu () {

    // Establish return value and validation
    int menuSelection;
    string userInput;
    bool menuSelectionIsValid = false;

    do {

        // Print options
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "[1] Add Account" << "\n";
        cout << "[2] Remove Account" << "\n";
        cout << "[3] Update Account" << "\n";
        cout << "[4] Search Account" << "\n";
        cout << "[5] Make A Deposit" << "\n";
        cout << "[6] Make A Withdrawal" << "\n";
        cout << "[7] Check Balance" << "\n";
        cout << "[8] Logout" << "\n";
        cout << "Please enter a selection";
        cout << "\n";
        getline(cin, userInput);

        // Validate input
        if (userInput == "1") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 1;
        }

        else if (userInput == "2") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 2;
        }

        else if (userInput == "3") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 3;
        }

        else if (userInput == "4") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 4;
        }

        else if (userInput == "5") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 5;
        }

        else if (userInput == "6") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 6;
        }

        else if (userInput == "7") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 7;
        }

        else if (userInput == "8") {
            menuSelectionIsValid = true;
            menuSelection = 8;
        }

        else {
            cout << "Invalid input!" << "\n";
        }

    } while (!menuSelectionIsValid);

    return menuSelection;
}

// Locate account and print relevant information
void searchAccount(string fileName) {

    // Establish arrays
    string accountNumber[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountSSN[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountName[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountAddress[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountPhone[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];

    // Establish validation variables
    string userInput;
    bool accountFound = false;

    // Establish and validate fin
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    if (!fin.is_open()) {
        cout << "File cannot be opened " << fileName << "\n";
    }

    // Get desired account number
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "Account number: ";
    getline(cin, userInput);

    // Read information from file
    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
        getline(fin, accountNumber[i]);
        getline(fin, accountSSN[i]);
        getline(fin, accountName[i]);
        getline(fin, accountAddress[i]);
        getline(fin, accountPhone[i]);
    }

    // Search for account
    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
        if (accountNumber[i] == userInput && userInput != "") {
            accountFound = true;
        }

        // Display account information
        if (accountFound == true) {
            cout << "Account Found" << "\n";
            cout << "Displaying account information" << "\n" << "\n";
            cout << accountNumber[i] << "\n";
            cout << accountSSN[i] << "\n";
            cout << accountName[i] << "\n";
            cout << accountAddress[i] << "\n";
            cout << accountPhone[i] << "\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    // Inform user that account doesnt exist
    if (accountFound == false) {
        cout << "Unable to find account: " << userInput << "\n";
    }
}

void addAccount(string fileName) {

    string accountNumber[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountSSN[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountName[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountAddress[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountPhone[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];

    ifstream fin(fileName);
    // ofstream fout(fileName);

    string userAccountNumber;
    string userAccountSSN;
    string userAccountName;
    string userAccountAddress;
    string userAccountPhone;

    bool accountNumberIsTaken = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
        getline(fin, accountNumber[i]);
        getline(fin, accountSSN[i]);
        getline(fin, accountName[i]);
        getline(fin, accountAddress[i]);
        getline(fin, accountPhone[i]);
    }

    do {

        accountNumberIsTaken = false;

        cout << "\n";
        cout << "Enter desired account number: ";
        getline(cin, userAccountNumber);

        for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
            if (userAccountNumber == accountNumber[i] || userAccountNumber == "") {
                cout << "That account number is already in use" << "\n";
                accountNumberIsTaken = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (accountNumberIsTaken);

    /*

    cout << "Enter SSN: ";
    getline(cin, userAccountSSN);
    cout << "Enter full name: ";
    getline(cin, userAccountName);
    cout << "Enter address: ";
    getline(cin, userAccountAddress);
    cout << "Enter phone number: ";
    getline(cin, userAccountPhone);

    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
        if (accountNumber[i] == "") {
            cout << "empty space found at" << i;
            accountNumber[i] = userAccountNumber;
            accountSSN[i] = userAccountSSN;
            accountName[i] = userAccountName;
            accountAddress[i] = userAccountAddress;
            accountPhone[i] = userAccountPhone;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
        fout << accountNumber[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountSSN[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountName[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountAddress[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountPhone[i] << "\n";
    }

    */
}
```

The issue:

The base code, without anything commented out, does not work at all.

Both the **accountSearch()** and **addAccount()** functions which rely on reading **"accounts.txt"** will report that an account number clearly present on **"accounts.dat"** is not present.

After commenting out **ofstream fout(fileName);** and the lower part of the **addAccount()** that relies on writing to the file **AND** making a slight change to the **"accounts.txt"** file and saving changes, things start working again

This project is being written in Visual Studio 2019.

Apologies if this is a poor explanation. Please ask for clarification if necessary.

Comment: what is the question

Comment: You can't have `filename` opened as both an `ifstream` and an `ofstream` at the same time.

Comment: After you finish reading the file, close it and reopen it for writing. Don't declare ifs and ofs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `filename` opened as both an `ifstream` and an `ofstream` at the same time! So, move your declaration/constructor for `fout` to after the code for reading `fin`, like this:

```cpp
void addAccount(string fileName) {
    string accountNumber[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountSSN[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountName[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountAddress[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];
    string accountPhone[ACCOUNTS_SIZE];

    ifstream fin(fileName);
    // ofstream fout(fileName); /// CANNOT BE HERE!

    string userAccountNumber;
    ///... Here, have all your reading and input code (as it is) …
    ///...

    ///... Finished reading, etc., so CLOSE "fin" then get the "fout" …
    fin.close();
    ofstream fout(fileName); // NOW we can create the output stream!
    ///... and use your existing code to do the writing

    for (int i = 0; i < ACCOUNTS_SIZE; i++) {
        fout << accountNumber[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountSSN[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountName[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountAddress[i] << "\n";
        fout << accountPhone[i] << "\n";
    }
    fout.close(); /// When finished, CLOSE the file!
}
```